# No suitable method found for fill int int in Java

Tags: java, syntax-error

I want to initialize a two-dimensional array with `MAX_VALUE`, but meet some errors.

```
class Solution {
    public int strangePrinter(String s) {

        int[][] dp = new int[s.length()][s.length()];
        char[] charArray = s.toCharArray();

        for (int j = 0; j < s.length(); j++) {
            for (int k = 0; k < s.length(); k++) {
                Arrays.fill(dp[j][k], Integer.MAX_VALUE);
            }
        }
        return dp[0][s.length()-1];
  }
}
```

Error:

```
no suitable method for fill int int
```

How to solve this error?

Comment: What is the point of this code? it created some array and then returns only 1 element out of it?

Comment: This whole function could be replaced with: `return Integer.MAX_VALUE;` :)

Comment: I just post some of my codes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just set the value:

Instead of

`Arrays.fill(dp[j][k], Integer.MAX_VALUE);`

Use:

```
dp[j][k] = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
```

### Understanding the error message

`no suitable method for fill int int`

Because Java allows overloading of methods ist sesrches for the method, that fits the Parameters best. In your case it searches for:

`void fill(int, int) {/*...*/}`

but because there is no such method defined in `Arrays` you get this error message.

[At the official docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html) you can find all possible signatures (parameters)

Answer (score 1):

`Arrays.fill(int[], int)` takes an `int` array and an `int` value, not two `int`s.

```
for (int j = 0; j < s.length(); j++) {
    Arrays.fill(dp[j], Integer.MAX_VALUE);
}
```